# Resharper warnings as Visualstudio errors

Tags: warnings, resharper

Is there any way to show all resharper code review warnings as errors in Visual Studio 2012? 
I tried checking options in Resharper tab in VS2012 but could not figure it out. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `Resharper`->`Options...`->`Code Inspection`->`Inspection Severity`

[image]

Comment: I am at that page before but could not find the correct place where I can change all warnings to errors at a time. Could you please guide me on that.

Comment: I seem to remember in an older version of Resharper you could change whole groups at a time but they have removed that feature.